# Can't get bottle to import route

Tags: python, python-2.7, bottle

I am trying to get bottle to run the simple python script that bottle makes available on its download site on a Mac running El Capitan. I have imported bottle with pip install in my directory /Users/michaelreinhard$. I am running Python 2.7.

bottle seems to install with no problems but when I try to run the script provided on the bottle website:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I get the error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name route
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I found a similar question from about three years ago where a guy ran into the same problem running things from a virtual environment. The answer in his case was to change the name of the file from bottle.py to mybottle.py but that didn't work for me.

UPDATE:

I don't know if this is relevant but I saw on the MongoDB tutorial that the bottle package was installed in the /usr/local/bin/ directory. I checked on my own system and saw that bottle was not installed in that directory. So, I tried to install it there, running pip install from that /usr/local/bin/ directory and got back the message:

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bottle in /Users/michaelreinhard/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I guess that it installed it in the anaconda library. I don't know if that is part of the problem or not but I thought I would mention it.

Comment: Do you have a file or directory, in your current directory, named `bottle`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out. I into another directory and ran

python -c "import bottle"

And then moved the script into that directory and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

rename the file to mybottle.py and try again